# Is it possible to keep both the domain and the subdomain into single route 53 zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

It seems that the information regarding configuring both a domain and subdomain on aws route 53 is not quite complete and I would like to know if is possible to keep all records in a single zone.

Example of records that needs to be resolvable:
* example.com
* a.example.com
* b.a.example.com

I do know that in order to make the `b.a.example.com` resolvable you need to add NS records inside `a.example.com` but it is this enough?

Amazon allows you to add any records inside the same zone so I suspect this may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add all of these in one zone, and you do *not* need `NS` records for `a.example.com` to get `b.a.example.com` to work in this scenario.

Comment: Yep, it was a mistake to try to configure NS servers for this subzone as this would break the zone. The easiest way to configure it to keep all subzones in the main one. This works well with AWS, not to mention that avoids paying the monthly charge for creating a new zone.